Filter in the feedback path of the current control loop
I have a current control loop of a dc-dc converter (for the question it doesn't matter what is its topology). The control loop has following configuration (\$D (s)\$ is a transfer function of the current controller, \$C (s)\$ is the transfer function of the plant i.e. cascade of the modulator transfer function and \$RL\$ load transfer function)

The reference value (\$\color{blue}{i^{ref}}\$) and actual value (\$\color{red}{i^{act}}\$) of the current is following

Now I have exactly the same current control loop as above with one difference. Namely I have added a low pass filter (with transfer function \$H(s)\$) in the feedback path

The reference value (\$\color{blue}{i^{ref}}\$) and actual value (\$\color{red}{i^{act}}\$) of the current for this case (along with the filtered current \$\color{green}{i^{act}_{filt}}\$) is following

It could be said from the above given graphs that the low pass filter in the feedback path has no influence on the current control loop behavior. I would say it means that

the noise present in the controlled current is above the bandwith of the current control loop (i.e. the current control loop doesn't react to it eithter without filtering)
the nature of the controlled current isn't given by the current controller (maybe it's given by some problem in the modulator)

My question is whether the above given conclusions are correct?

idk if I'm getting too old but I can't read the legend on your plots. Would you care to explain what is red blue and green?

I'd say that your filter corner is above the bandwidth of the control loop if it hasn't significantly degraded your phase margin or made your loop unstable.  I don't know if all of your noise is outside the BW of the loop, look at the noise spectrum- If the loop isn't reacting significantly, chances are it is mostly outside the BW.   I also don't know what you mean by the "nature" of the controlled current.  If it's controlled, (and stable) then the loop is controlling it withing its bandwidth.  Anything outside the bandwidth (your noise?) is coming from somewhere else, like switching noise.

@KenGrimes thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to incorporate explanation to the individual traces into the text of the question.

Thanks @Steve for the added colors.

The system analysis tells me that from the noise point of view things are getting worse as can be seen from the analysis done for various cases of reacted system:


The measured current appears to show a huge ripple, is that according to design (probably inductor size)? At that time resolution it's hard to say if it is noise or the ripple due switching of the converter, in that case it is to be expected that the controller operates with lower bandwidth.
Regarding your second question: It would be necessary to see a step change in the reference signal in order to see if the controlled current is being affected by the controller
